# String types not allowed (at 'id' with value ' @id/bAdd')

Tags: android, xml

I am getting an error saying 
**String types not allowed (at 'id' with value ' @id/bAdd')**

- I've cleaned the project.
- Everything was working earlier, I don't what happened, causing this error.

  ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:text="Your total is 0"
      android:textSize="45dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
      tools:context=".StartingPoint" />

   <Button 
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Subtract One"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:id="+@id/bSub"
      />


  <Button 
      android:layout_width="250dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Add One"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:id="+@id/bAdd"

      />
  ```

Comment: Do you get the solution? then you can accept answer

Answer (score 19):

You can give your id as `@+id/bAdd`

instead of `+@id/bAdd`

Also edit in

```
android:id="@+id/bSub"
            ^^
```

instead of

```
android:id="+@id/bSub"
            ^^
```

Answer (score 3):

**+** Symbol must be after **@** Symbol.

```
android:id="+@id/bAdd" to  android:id="@+id/bAdd"

 and also change

android:id="+@id/bSub" to android:id="@+id/bSub"
```

**OR**

you can declare is it

android:id="@id/bSub"

but you have to declare bSub value in ids.xml file located in values folder.

## Example

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="bSub" />
```

Answer (score 1):

please use `@+id/yourId` instead of `@id/yourId`